# Listview skips first column

Tags: c#, windows, forms, listview

With this code I add values in my columns. But the first column is constantly skipped.

This is the code I use:

```
        foreach (Muziek m in lijstMuziek)
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
            lvi.SubItems.Add(m.Rapper);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(m.Titel);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(m.DuurMinuut.ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
```

[image: Listview]

I changed the displayindex, but that doesn't matter.

Anyone got a clue why this could happen?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first item's text goes in `ListViewItem.Text`. The subitems are for subsequent columns.

Comment: Because this makes complete sense....

Thank you for the answer.  This stumped me for 20 minutes; when I realized my code looked right, i figured it was some stupid nuance in VB.NET.